# Laravel 8 sanctum api "CSRF token mismatch" 419 error with next.js app

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I am getting the message: "CSRF token mismatch. error while using laravel sanctum api with Next.js app.

```
POST https://xyzdomain.api/login 419

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 419
at e.exports (7269-1f09c32afb5696ba.js:1:5531)
at e.exports (7269-1f09c32afb5696ba.js:1:7980)
at XMLHttpRequest.g (7269-1f09c32afb5696ba.js:1:782)
```

Everything is working fine on localhost, but getting the above error while I make the app live on the production server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get [csrf cookie](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#csrf-protection) first.
As per laravel's documentation :

> To authenticate your SPA, your SPA's "login" page should first make a
> request to the /sanctum/csrf-cookie endpoint to initialize CSRF
> protection for the application

This request will return a set-cookie header to set CSRF Token in the cookie.

!------ This is not recommend for web app. But may be of value to some -------!

Also, if you choose to (NOT RECOMMENDED), you can disable CSRF validation for api routes. Just modify `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` to add `/api/*` inside the `$except` array. It should look something like this:

```
    protected $except = [
        '/api/*'
    ];
```

Comment: I have a PWA that isn't an SPA, but seems like it may suffer from this same issue on mobile Safari, perhaps for caching reasons. Would the Sanctum CSRF advice also apply to that scenario to get a fresh CSRF token? I'd need to manually insert it into the login form in the success callback.